# Find a delta for a specific epsilon.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f: [1, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) = \frac{x-[x]}{[x]}$ where [x] is the largest integer $n$ with $n\le x$.

The question asks to find $\delta > 0$ such that if $|x-3|< \delta$ then $|f(x)-f(3)|< \frac{1}{2}$.

When I tried to solve this, I found out that $f(x)$ is not continuous at $3$ and that $f(x)$ approaches $\frac{1}{2}$ as $x$ approaches $3$, so I cannot find any $\delta$ that is suitable, and I am not sure what to do.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- For $x \in (2,3)$ we have $$f(x) = \frac{x-2}{2}.$$ Since $f(3)=0$, $$|f(x)-f(3)| = |f(x)|< \frac{1}{2}$$ is satisfied if $$\left| \frac{x-2}{2} \right| < \frac{1}{2},$$ i.e. if $|x-2| <1$. Thus, $|f(x)-f(3)|< \frac{1}{2}$ for all $x \in (2,3)$.
- Let $x \in (3,4)$. Then $$f(x) = \frac{x-3}{3}; $$ hence$$|f(x)-f(3)|< \frac{1}{2}$$ if $$\left| \frac{x-3}{3} \right| < \frac{1}{2},$$ i.e. if $|x-3|< \frac{3}{2}$. This means that $|f(x)-f(3)| < \frac{1}{2}$ holds for all $x \in (3,4)$.

Consequently, we can choose any $\delta \in (0,1)$.

Comment: Thank you for helping. This question also asks "How big can $|f(x)-f(3)|$ be if $|x-3|< 2/3$?" I said that the biggest $|f(x)-f(3)|$ can be is 1/2, but after seeing how you solved the problem, I am not sure if my answer is correct or not.

Comment: @Lucy Well, $|f(x)-f(3)|$ is always smaller than $\frac{1}{2}$. Note however, that there does not exist an $x$ (from the given interval) such that $|f(x)-f(3)| = \frac{1}{2}$. It really helps to draw a picture of the given function.

Comment: I was thinking something like $x=2.\overline{9}$, so should I not consider something like this? But then what should I say as the biggest value?

Comment: @Lucy Yes, that's basically correct. $|f(x)-f(3)| < \frac{1}{2}$ is the best estimate we can expect. Nevertheless, $f$ does not attain its maximum, i.e. there is no biggest value.

Answer (score 0):

You could use $\delta = 1$ since  from $2$ up to just to the left of $3$ the function goes up from just above $0$ to, but not all the way up to $+1/2$, while exactly at $3$ it is $0,$ and from $3$ up to just before $4$ it goes only up to just below $1/3$.

You're right about it's not being continuous at $3$, that would require that for *every* $\varepsilon$ there is a $\delta$ etc.

Comment: Thank you for helping. This question also asks "How big can $|f(x)-f(3)|$ be if $|x-3|< 2/3$?" I said that the biggest $|f(x)-f(3)|$ can be is 1/2, but after seeing how you solved the problem, I am not sure if my answer is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

$f(3) = 0$. So you need to find a $\delta$ such that in the open interval $(3-\delta, 3+\delta)$, $f(x) < \frac{1}{2}$.

As you observed, the limit  of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $3$ from below is $1\over 2$. But that is no problem since in the open interval $(2,3)$, $f(x) = \frac{x-2}{2} < \frac{3-2}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$.  And for all $x \geq 3$, $f(x) < \frac{1}{3} < \frac{1}{2}$.

So for any $\delta \leq 1$, $x \in (3-\delta, 3+\delta) \rightarrow f(x) < \frac{1}{2}$.

Since  $x \in (\frac{3}{2},2) \rightarrow  f(x) > \frac{1}{2}$, the largest $\delta$ you could use that satisfies the requirement is in fact $\delta = 1$.

Comment: Thank you for helping. This question also asks "How big can $|f(x)-f(3)|$ be if $|x-3|< 2/3$?" I said that the biggest $|f(x)-f(3)|$ can be is 1/2, but after seeing how you solved the problem, I am not sure if my answer is correct or not.